# Not sure why my limit is not being reached

Tags: javascript, while-loop, visual-studio-code

I cannot seem to reach my limit on a variable that should max up to 20. There is an inner loop which should test that all numbers between 1 and 20 can be divided by the variable in the outer loop, without any decimal places - so whole numbers. When limit = 20 I return out of the outer loop and have the outer variable that I know can be divided by every iteration of the inner loop. Seems pretty easy. Vscode does not get far, I never reach above limit = 10. It seems like my vs compiler just bottoms out.

Any ideas? much obliged...

```
let starter = 2520;
let limit = 0;

while (limit < 20) {
  let i = 1;

  while (i <= 20) {
    if (starter % i !== 0) {
      limit = 0;
      break;
    }
    limit = i;
    i++;
  }
  if (limit === 20) {
    return starter;
  }
  starter++;
}
```

Should exit at

```
limit === 20
```

Comment: The number you are searching, being divisible through all integers between 1 and 20, is 232792560 (2*2*2*2*3*3*5*7*11*13*17*19) - and that takes quite some iterations!

Comment: @Bergi How/Where did you run this code successfully? If you are correct that it can run fine, then maybe the issue really is just VSCode as the OP implied?

Comment: @DanFriedman I just put it in my Chrome devtools console (where it took a few seconds - not an eternity but still). Yes, my guess is that running the code in the vscode debugger, maybe even with some breakpoints enabled, slows this down heavily. (To see a `limit` of `11`, one would have to do `27720 - 2520` iterations)

Comment: Without solving the issue, can I suggest that you always increment `starter` by `20`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are using a `return` sentence inside your while loop, which actually doesn't `break` the loop.

> *Remember that `return` is used to go back to the step where it was called, while `break` is used to end a loop.*

With this said, you should first `break` the loop and after it, `return` what you need to return.

If you replace the only appearance of `return` in your code with `break`, you will be able to see the result in `starter` variable.

```js
let starter = 2520;
let limit = 0;

while (limit < 20) {
  let i = 1;

  while (i <= 20) {
    if (starter % i !== 0) {
      limit = 0;
      break;
    }
    limit = i;
    i++;
  }
  if (limit === 20) {
    break; // Use break, not return
  }
  starter++;
}

console.log(limit)
console.log(starter)
```

It will end the while loop when `limit === 20`.

> *As @Bergi mentioned, if your code resides inside a function, you can then replace `console.log(starter)` with `return starter`.*

Comment: You'd have to assume that this code is placed inside a `function`, and of course `return` would break out there.

Comment: @Bergi True, but `return starter` after the main while loop should do it.

Comment: No, OP wants to `return starter` before it is incremented. You'd have to do `return starter - 1` after the loop.

Comment: @Bergi and the `break` sentence does exactly that. It jumps right outside the main while loop. That's why you can read the result from `starter`.

Comment: This was a great answer. Of course - why am I returning but not in a function, usually I am - that's why. As soon as I replaced ***return*** with ***break*** I hit the limit. thanks @k3llydev

Comment: Always glad to help, happy coding @godhar!

Answer (score 0):

Thought process:

1. `limit` is set at 3 locations. Twice it is set to `0` and only once to `i`.
2. `i` is declared at the beginning of the outer-while and is always reset to `1`.
3. So the only way for `limit` to reach `20` is for `i` to reach `20`, within one iteration of the outer-loop.
4. `i` only increments in the inner loop, so `i` must reach `20` within the inner loop
5. In order to reach `20`, `i` must divide evenly into `starter` for every number tested (i.e. 1..20). I'm guessing that never happens.
6. It can only exit when `limit` is `20` or greater, so the program is in an infinite loop.

If you add some `console.log` statements or step through the code, you'll see the problem.

Comment: It's not an infinite loop. You can try to run it: the result is 232792560. Apart from your guess in #5, all your statements are a correct analysis :-)

Comment: Ah, you're right. I didn't catch that `starter` was being incremented. So it just feels like infinity (eternity) and has crashed the online JavaScript runners I've tried. :)

Comment: Yes, that was my first guess as well: 2520 is not divisible by all these numbers, so it's an infinite loop - until I noticed the `starter++`…